# Javascript sprites moving between two points

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to get some sprites moving between two points in my (very basic) javascript game. Each sprite is randomly placed in the level, so I want them to move back and forth between their base position. I have the code below

```
function Taniwha(pos) {
this.basePos = this.pos;
this.size = new Vector(0.6, 1);
this.move = basePos + moveDist(5,0));
}
Taniwha.prototype.type = "taniwha"

var moveSpeed = 4;
Taniwha.prototype.act = function(step) {
this.move = ???
```

and this is where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to tell it to go left, back to base pos, right then back to base pos again (I plan to loop this). Does anyone have any advice? (also using Eloquen Javascript's example game as an outline/guide for this, if how I'm doing things seems odd!)

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal movement, change x coordinate of the position.

```
var pos = { x: 1, y: 2 };
pos.x++ ; // This will move right
pos.x-- ; // This will move left
```

Likewise for vertical movement. You also need to update the coordinates after change for the object which you are drawing.

Answer (score 0):

In truth ,there are lots of library to develop a game.
Use those, control a sprite is very easy.
Like:
[Pixijs](http://www.pixijs.com/)
[CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/)

Both of them are opensource project, you can watch and learn the source.
And have lots of examples and document.